Different $\sigma$-algebras on the space of Borel probability measures on a metric space
This question is intended to distill the core components of this sister question on MathOverflow for increased visibility and transparency.
Let $X$ be a metrizable topological space and $\mathscr B_X$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on it. Let $\Delta X$ denote the set of probability measures on $(X,\mathscr B_X)$, and let $\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$, which is defined as the weakest topology on $\Delta X$ that makes the map $\mathbb P\mapsto\int_X f(x)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(x)$ continuous for every bounded and continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb R$. Finally, let $\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$ denote the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the real line.
Consider another $\sigma$-algebra on $\Delta X$ generated by sets of the form $\{\mathbb P\in\Delta X\,|\,\mathbb P(A)\in E\}$ for $A\in\mathscr B_X$ and $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$; denote this $\sigma$-algebra as $\mathscr F$. This thread shows that $$\mathscr F\subseteq\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$$ without further assumptions (but see this thread for how this inclusion may fail if $X$ is not metrizable), whereas the converse inclusion $$\mathscr B_{\Delta X}\subseteq\mathscr F$$ holds under the additional assumption that the metric topology on $X$ (and hence the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$) is separable (and thus second countable).
What I am interested in is constructing an explicit counterexample showing that the inclusion $$\mathscr F\subset\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$$ may hold strictly if $X$ is not separable. I suspect that a natural counterexample would involve an uncountable set endowed with the discrete metric, but I can’t quite put my finger on how the details would work out. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I document here a (so far incomplete) attempt. Let $X$ be an uncountable set endowed with the discrete topology. Clearly, $X$ is not separable and $\mathscr B_X$ is the power set of $X$. For any $x\in X$, let $\delta_x$ denote the Dirac measure at $x$. I have been able to prove that if $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$, then $\{\delta_x\,|\,x\in A\}$ is in $\mathscr B_{\Delta X}$. (In fact, each such set is $G_{\delta}$ with respect to the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$.) It feels that $\mathscr F$ is not rich enough to contain all such sets, but an exact disproof still eludes me. What I have tried is constructing some subset $\mathscr E$ of the power set of $\Delta X$ such that

$\mathscr E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (defined by some crucial condition that would come in handy);
each set of the form $\{\mathbb P\in\Delta X\,|\,\mathbb P(A)\in E\}$ with $A\in\mathscr B_X$ and $E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}$ is in $\mathscr E$ (therefore, $\mathscr F\subseteq\mathscr E$); but
there is some $A\subseteq X$ (perhaps an uncountable set whose complement is also uncountable) such that $\{\delta_x\,|\,x\in A\}\notin\mathscr E$.


I think the approach of considering Dirac measures on some discrete space might not work. In particular, if $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the discrete topology (or anything with the same cardinality since we can use a bijection), then $D_A \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $A \subseteq X$.
The key thing here is that, although $X$ is not separable, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can partition $X$ into a countable family $\{A_{n,k}\}$ of Borel sets such that every $x \in X$ is equal to a nested intersection of sets, one from each partition, and every nested intersection is equal to a point. i.e.
$$
\forall x \in X, x = \bigcap_n A_{n,k_n} \text{ where } k_n \text{ is the unique index such that } x \in A_{n,k_n}
$$
and
$$
\text{for every sequence } \{k_n\}, \exists x \text{ such that } x = \bigcap_n A_{n,k_n}
$$
$\{A_{n,k}\}$ being a partition of $X$ into half-open intervals of length $2^{-n}$ works. We can restrict each interval to get a corresponding partition of $A$ with the same property.
Then $\{\mathbb{P} \in \Delta X : \mathbb{P}(A_{n,k}) = 1\} \in \mathcal{F}$, and consequently
$$
B = \bigcap_n \bigcup_k \{\mathbb{P} \in \Delta X : \mathbb{P}(A_{n,k}) = 1\} \in \mathcal{F} 
$$
I claim $B = D_A$. The inclusion $D_A \subset B$ is clear, since if $\delta_x \in D_A$, for every $n$ there is some $A_{n,k}$ that contains $x$, and then $\delta_x(A_{n,k}) = 1$. To see $B \subset D_A$, suppose $\mathbb{P} \in B$. Then for each $n$ there is a unique $k_n$ for which $\mathbb{P}(A_{n,k_n}) = 1$ and it follows that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_n A_{n,k_n}\right) = 1
$$
so $\mathbb{P}$ is the Dirac measure of an element of $A$.

Edit: Having now seen user95282's counterexample here, we were very close! The set of Dirac measures on a discrete space does work if $X$ is any bigger than $\mathbb{R}$. I should have realised that would prevent the existence of such partitions. I would now like to conjecture that, for $X$ metrizable, the inclusion $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathscr{B}_{\Delta X}$ is proper iff such partitions $A_{n,k}$ exist. This is a slightly weaker property than separability. In particular, I suspect $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{B}_{\Delta X}$ when $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. Note the existence of such partitions is equivalent to the existence of a countable collection of Borel subsets of $X$ which distinguishes every pair of points in $X$.
The argument in the sister thread shows that the set $D$ of Dirac measures does not belong to $\mathcal{F}$ if $|X| > \mathfrak{c}$. Showing $D \in \mathscr{B}_{\Delta X}$ is immediate if $X$ is discrete since the indicator function of a singleton ${x}$ will be continuous. However, for any metrisable space $X$, if we fix a metric $d(x,y)$ we can write indicator functions of singletons as pointwise limits of continuous functions, e.g. set
$$f_{x,n} (y) = \max(1 - d(x,y), 0).$$
We can then write
$$
D = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{x \in X} \left\{\mu : \int_X f_{x,n} \mathrm{d}\mu > \frac{n-1}{n}\right\}
$$
Showing this equality is not totally trivial, but it follows since the support of each $f_{n,x}$ is a closed ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$, if $\mu$ belongs to the LHS we have sets $A_1, A_2, \dots$ such that $\mu(A_n) > \frac{n-1}{n}$ and the diameter of the $A_n$ goes to $0$. So we have
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=n} ^\infty A_k \right) = 1
$$
for every $n$, and thus
$$
\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1} ^\infty \bigcup_{k=n} ^\infty A_k \right) = 1
$$
So it must be non-empty, and we can show it can't contain more than one point. Suppose $x\ne y$ are both elements. For every $n$ there must exist $k>n$ and $m>n$ such that $x \in A_k$ and $y \in A_m$. Picking sufficiently large $n$ such that these must be disjoint yields a contradiction as $\mu(A_k) + \mu(A_m) > 1$.
Thus $D \in \mathscr{B}_{\Delta X}$ and every metrisable space of cardinality greater than the continuum yields a counterexample. Indeed, this proof goes through whenever there does not exist a countable collection of Borel subsets of $X$ that distinguishes all pairs of points, proving one direction of the conjecture.

Thank you for your answer. You are right, and your example suggests that working in an uncountable discrete space while trying to target the Dirac measures is unlikely to be a fruitful approach. That said, I still lean towards believing that a counterexample does exist. The reason is as follows. [cont’d below]

[cont’d from above] Let $\mathscr S$ be the collection of sets of the form $$\left{\mathbb P\in\Delta X\text{ such that }\left|\int_{x\in X}f(x),\mathrm d\mathbb P(x)-y\right|<\varepsilon\right},$$ where $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is bounded and continuous, $y\in\mathbb R$, and $\varepsilon>0$. By definition, $\mathscr S$ is a subbase for the weak-star topology on $\Delta X$. If $X$ is metrizable, then $\mathscr S$ and ${{\mathbb P\in\Delta X,|,\mathbb P(A)\in E},|,A\in\mathscr B_X\text{ and }E\in\mathscr B_{\mathbb R}}$ generate the same $\sigma$-algebra on $\Delta X$. [cont’d below]

[cont’d from above] But if $X$ is not separable, I have serious doubts as to the possibility that the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathscr S)$ generated on $\Delta X$ by the topological subbase $\mathscr S$ and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open sets could coincide.

Yes, after reading through the linked threads thoroughly I'm inclined to agree that an explicit counterexample can be constructed. The set of all probability measures $\mu$ such that $\mu(A) = 0 $ for some co-countable $A \subset X$ is $G_\delta$ in $\mathscr{B}_{\Delta X}$ as well.  Whether that belongs to $\mathcal{F}$ is what I'm considering now.

If you endow $X=\mathbb R$ with its power set as the $\sigma$-algebra, then, assuming the continuum hypothesis, it is possible that for any probability measure $\mu\in\Delta X$, there exists some co-countable set $A\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(A)=0$. This possibility cannot be excluded within ZFC. But the set of probability measures that have finite support is $G_{\delta\sigma}$ (countable union of $G_{\delta}$ sets) in $\Delta X$ and hence Borel; I wonder if working with this set could establish a counterexample.

Oops, that's a big oversight from me, thank you for pointing it out! The set of measures with finite support unfortunately doesn't work. Call this set $B$, and the set of measures with support of size $\le m$ by $B_m$. We can tackle this using the partition ${A_{n,k}}$ as above. Noting that $\mathbb{P} \in B_m$ iff for every $n$ there exists an m-tuple $(n_1,\dots, n_m)$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1} ^m A_{n,k_{n_i}}) = 1$, as there are countably many such $m$-tuples we can write $B_m$ as a $G_{\sigma\delta}$ in $\mathscr{F}$, and hence $B$ is a $G_{\sigma\delta\sigma}$.

Yes, I agree with you on the judgment that the matter cannot be settled on $(\mathbb R,2^{\mathbb R})$ by reference to probability measures of finite support, either, given your partitional construction. At any rate, the answer by user95282 on MathOverflow settles the question of the existence of some non-separable counterexample—although the question of whether an explicit counterexample can be constructed on $(\mathbb R,2^{\mathbb R})$ remains an open (and interesting) one. Thank you for thinking with me on this!
